# Expo-av audio recording

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to record audio with `expo-audio` but it's showing an error when I start recording `Error: Only one Recording object can be prepared at a given time.`
and `Error: Cannot unload a Recording that has not been prepared.` I also followed the documentation but still getting same error.

below is my code for starting recording

```
  const [recording, setRecording] = React.useState();

  async function startRecording() {
    try {
      console.log('Requesting permissions..');
      await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: true,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      }); 
      console.log('Starting recording..');
      const recording = new Audio.Recording();
      await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY);
      await recording.startAsync(); 
      setRecording(recording);
      console.log('Recording started');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to start recording', err);
    }
  }
```

and for stop recording

```
async function stopRecording() {
    console.log('Stopping recording..');
    setRecording(undefined);
    await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
    const uri = recording.getURI(); 
    console.log('Recording stopped and stored at', uri);
  }
```

anyone know why I'm getting that error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `recording` as a state variable. Re-rendering makes the variable initialize again and again

Outside of the funtion or the class you are using declare a variable like this

```
let recording = new Audio.Recording();
```

Then use like this this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from "expo-av";

let recording = new Audio.Recording();

export default function App() {
  async function startRecording() {
    try {
      console.log('Requesting permissions..');
      await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: true,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      });
      console.log('Starting recording..');
      await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(
        Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY
      );
      await recording.startAsync();
      console.log('Recording started');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to start recording', err);
    }
  }

  async function stopRecording() {
    console.log('Stopping recording..');
    await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
    const uri = recording.getURI();
    console.log('Recording stopped and stored at', uri);
  }

  return <View>// Your App contents here</View>;
}
```

Comment: it worked thanks, it's currently creating m4a file can you tell me how to make it mp3?

Comment: i think saving as mp3 has not yet implemented by Expo

Comment: Just change the configuration:
 
recording.prepareToRecordAsync(
        Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY
      );
to
recording.prepareToRecordAsync(
            {
              android: {
                extension: '.mp3',
                outputFormat: 2,
                audioEncoder: 3,
                sampleRate: 44100,
                numberOfChannels: 2,
                bitRate: 128000
              }
            }
          )